# how to [professionally/correct way] insert php code into javascript and/or html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, methods

For instance,
in javascript:
1

```
<script>
var name = "<?php echo 'Adam'; ?>";
alert("The name is: " + name);
</script>
```

or
2

```
<script>
alert("The name is: <?php echo 'Adam'; ?>");
</script>
```

And in html?
1

```
<head>
<?php echo '<title>Page #1</title>'; ?>
</head>
```

or
2

```
<?php $page_number = "1"; ?> // on top of the script with the rest of the other X code. //
<!doctype html....
<html>
<head>
<title>Page #<?php echo $page_number; ?></title>
</head>
```

I'm **not** looking for the short, long, easy or hard method, I'm looking for the correct method to do this.

1 - In a professional way, how this should be done?

2 - What is your way/method to do this?

Thanks

Update:
Also:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:add_friend(0,<?php echo $profile_user_id; ?>);" />
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no *correct* method. Rather, there are conventions that you will find yourself using, or your team will find itself using. Further, it is at times a *case by case* situation where your HTML may need to be processed a bit by PHP prior to being spit out, and other times it may not.

I happen to *prefer* seeing as clean as separation as possible, where the limits of the PHP tags are shared by the same limits of any code we would hard-wire into place.

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<script>
  var strValue = <?php echo json_encode( $strValue ); ?>;
</script>
```

But again, *that's just me*.

With regards to JavaScript within HTML attributes, I would encourage you to stay as far away from that as you can. Rather than using `onclick` attributes, bind all of this up in your JavaScript. This, again, keeps a clean line of separation between your structure and your logic.

Which would you prefer seeing in your markup:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:add_friend(0,288);" />
```

Or

```
<input type="button" data-action="add_friend" data-friendId="288" />
```

Keep your programmers out of your design, and more importantly your designers out of your code.

Comment: +1 I agree with your point of view. Echoing tags is completely unnecessary (and not much IDE-friendly), so this should be treated as a last resort. Also when passing PHP variables to JavaScript during page rendering, I prefer assigning their values to some JavaScript variables, or calling functions/methods that are created for that, or assigning variables to `data-` attributes of HTML elements, if they are somehow associated with HTML elements. But definitely not including PHP echo calls within JavaScript - one of the reasons is the problem with moving such script outside, to separate JS file.

Comment: For inserting onto JS, you **SHOULD** use json_encode, otherwise all bets are off if the generated data is actually synatically valid JS valid or not.